# appending certain columns in csv to another csv file is not spilting each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i found a little python code to create a new csv file with selected columns from another csv file
It is almost working correctly it just does not display each row on a new line. It is currently on the same line.

here is the code:

```
import csv

file_name =  'input.csv'
output_file = 'output.csv'
csv_file = open(file_name, 'r')
## note that the index of the year column is excluded
column_indices = [0,1,25,23,5,6,9,27,28,31,33,34,37,72,73,76,105,106,109,45,46,49]
with open(output_file, 'w') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
       tmp_row = []
       for col_inx in column_indices:
           tmp_row.append(row[col_inx])
       fh.write(','.join(tmp_row))
```

after the last column i need it to create a new row whereas currently everything is on the same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either use a `csv.writer` and use `.writerow` or write newline characters. One option is to use `print` with the `file=` option:

```
# replace this
# fh.write(','.join(tmp_row))
# with any of these:
print(*tmp_row, sep=",", file=fh) # default is end="\n" so you get rows
fh.writelines([','.join(tmp_row)])
fh.write(','.join(tmp_row) + '\n')
```